# Trouble building hello_world with a makefile in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build, makefile

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.console-dev.de/2009/09/03/create-nintendo-ds-applications-with-visual-studio-2008/) on making a hello_world program with Visual C++ 2010 express.  My hope in doing this is to get comfy with VC++ and eventually build a hello_world program that I can actually utilize on my handheld DS, but I am stuck at an early stage.  I am able to follow all instructions in the tutorial and achieve the correct results until I reach the bit titled "compile project".

When I click build hello_world, as it says to do in the tutorial, I receive this error from VC++ :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: hello_world, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(38,5): error     MSB3073: The command "make" exited with code 2.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have tried going into the hello_world properties, configuration properties, NMake and changing the 'include search path' to the directory containing the Makefile, which also contains the source folder for hello_world, but I get the same build error.  Please note: I am quite new to VC++ and programming in general, so I would not be surprised if this is not doing what I think it is doing.  I think it's changing the directory that VC++ looks in to find the make file, but please let me know if I am incorrect.

Other configuration properties include the following:

1. Output directory:  $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\
2. Intermediate directory: $(Configuration)\

   - (Does this have anything to do with my problem?  What is this?)

My current hello_world project in the solution explorer includes the main.cpp in the Source files folder and the Makefile.

I am doing this to learn, so if it seems like there is *anything* I am really misunderstanding, I would very much appreciate a bit of education on your part, or a link to a good resource for learning.  Also, I am having a bit of trouble conceptualizing everything that is going on with projects, solutions, source files, building, etc within visual C++ and the provided tutorials from Msoft have helped my ability to use VC++, but not really understand what I'm doing.  Does anyone know of a guide that might help me learn why I do certain things that I've been taught to do in visual c++?

Let me know if there is more information that I need to include!

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I just deleted all of the project files and folders and retried the tutorial, making sure to follow directions more carefully. I must have missed something the first time through, because it has now completed its build successfully. I don't think it was the path because I didn't change anything about that. The only thing I know I changed for sure was the output to hello_world.nds rather than hello_world.exe. I imagine that might have caused some issues, but maybe not. I'd still love links to any resources that might be able to excel my Visual C++ learning!